# How to convert a sketch into a vectorized image for a laser cutting?

Tags: vector, path, laser

I would like to scale the image to the final size.

As well as getting the boundaries more clear and the lines an even thickness.

This would have to be exported into a format that's transferable to CAD software for laser cutting.[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. 
It's hard to answer a question like this without seeing an example of the problem. Also what software are you using? Is the sketch a raster image? There's no way to automatically convert a raster image to vector unfortunately. Auto tracing is a possibility but very much dependent on the complexity or quality of the original raster image, the other option is to redraw the vectors manually.

Comment: The image... What image?

Comment: the image is shown above

Comment: Usually its best to manually draw the vectors. But your image is clean enough so the vectorizer might do a ok job.

Comment: Because you need centerlines for laser cutting, I'd manually redraw that. You can somewhat easily draw the light once and duplicate it.

Comment: ok. i managed to get it the correct line weight. it needs to be a final size of 1200mm x 900mm. i resized the artboard and image, but after exporting it the artboard returned to a vertical A3 sized view. any advice?